# Any c++ library to work with Md5 using class string?

Tags: c++, qt, hash

Is there any c++ standard library to work with Md5 hashing (and other hashes, possibly) by using the c++ `std::string` instead of `signed\unsigned char*`?. I found no implementation of this in `openssl/md5.h` since its function MD5 has this header: `unsigned char *MD5(const unsigned char *d, unsigned long n, unsigned char *md);`

I'm asking this because I'm trying to set a `QLabel lbResult`'s text to the result of the digest of the input of a string (coming from QString& arg1).

```
MD5((const unsigned char *) arg1.toStdString().c_str(),32,cryptResult);
ui->lbResult->setText(getStringFromUnsignedChar(cryptResult));
```

I had to build this `getStringFromUnsignedChar` which returns a `QString` object from the result but all these casting and this function could be avoided if I had something line `string MD5(string s);`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can simply use `std::string::data()` to retrieve the `char` array. If you need signed/unsigned version, use `reinterpret_cast`. Otherwise [Botan](https://botan.randombit.net/) is a modern C++11 Crypto library, and has [MD5 support](https://botan.randombit.net/doxygen/classBotan_1_1MD5.html) for `std::strings`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [QCryptographicHash](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcryptographichash.html). For example:

```
QByteArray hash = QCryptographicHash::hash(arg1.toUtf8(), QCryptographicHash::Md5);
ui->lbResult->setText(hash.toHex());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a wrapper:

```
std::string md5(const std::string &str) {
    std::array<unsigned char, MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH> result;
    MD5(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(str.data()), str.size(), result.data());

    return std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(result.data()), result.size());
}
```